# Console output to HTML File

Tags: java, automation, console, testng

Basically I'm running some automated tests using TestNG.

I'm using ITestListener to give real-time results of my tests status but this is outputted to the console.

Is there anyway of outputting the information on the console to a HTML file so I can view the progress from the html file?

I'm planning to create a HTML style report for my own benefit so more specifically would it be possible to place to output to specific parts of the HTML Report I create?

Overall I'm trying to achieve is a HTML file that I can open on Chrome while my tests are running and with an automatic refresh I can view the progress of the tests.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a solution that uses a small amount of JavaScript to update your browser window:
Your major file would be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function loadContentFile()
        {
            document.getElementById("content").innerHTML='<objecttype="type/html" data="content.html"></object>';
        }
        window.onload = setInterval(loadContentFile, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit:
Your Java program would write to a file called *content.html*. Just like you have done before. Nothing changes there. The "magic" happens by calling the *index.html* instead of the *content.html*. The *index.html* file when opened with a browser periodically loads the content of the *content.html* file thus realising a automatic reload of the page. 

Conclusion:
 You have a folder containing the *index.html* and *content.html*.
Your browser calls the *index.html*. Your Java program writes to the *content.html*.

Comment: Thanks @Andreas Brunnet . Thanks for the reply. Is it possible to implement this into a Java Class?

Comment: @colin Would you explain a bit more detailed what exactly you want implemented in Java?

Comment: I have an automation project that runs automated tests, the results of these tests are posted to a HTML file when the test is run. However if I view the html file I need to refresh it see the result of each test after it is completed. I want my code to refresh the html file continuously so I see the results appear automatically

Comment: @colin: I updated my answer so my intention should be more clear. The index.html is just a "wrapper" that periodically reloads another html file which is filled by your java program.